# How to make SimpleAdapter a Singleton in Android?

Tags: android, singleton, adapter, simpleadapter

i realized that if you try to extend the SimpleAdapter class, you must make the constructor public -

```
public MySimpleAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, data, resource, from, to);
}
```

but this will make it so that someone (or i) could accidentally create a new adapter, right?

i tried to make all of the data and methods static in the adapter, but it just doesn't seem like the right way to do things...? sorry, i don't mean to be too picky. i just don't want someone to accidentally instantiate an instance of MySimpleAdapter

How should i make this class a singleton?

the way i'm using SimpleAdapter is that i use it as a container to hold all the objects that i need in a dynamically shrinking/growing listview. At any point in the app, there should only be one such container. am i approaching this problem correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't want to make the adapter a static singleton. The reason for this is that it has a reference to the context. By making the adapter static, the context will never be garbage collected.

If anything, you want to keep a static instance of your `List`. On each activity, simply pass in a reference to the shared list and off you go.

Comment: Ahh. that makes perfect sense. though one thing - and i apologize if this is a dumb question, but what would happen if you don't garbage collect the context? is it really space-consuming? or is it that activity context lives in a stack and... if the an activity context (with a reference to List) ever gets put below another context, then you get data inconsistencies?

Comment: The Context is the source for all the resources in your app. Depending on which Context you leak, that can mean references to everything you've ever accessed within the application. So yes, it can be extremely sizable.

Answer (score 1):

Why must you make the constructor public? Ignoring the reasons for wanting to make it a singleton, it's entirely possible to declare your class that extends SimpleAdapter have a private constructor and have a public createInstance() method that implements a singleton pattern.

Comment: oops. sorry. that was my silly mistake. i should have tried it first. i was under the impression that in java when you override a class, you have to make the constructor public. but i guess it's only if the parent class specified its constructor to be public explicitly